# Pytest-mock: chain mocking between modules

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I am actuually writting unittests on a project.
While I am writting test functions, I am used to *mock* some function.

Recently, I am trying to mock a function that should write into a file.
Problem: This funct

Like below:

```py
# file A.py
def write_to_file(message, file="test.txt"):
    with open(file, "w") as fh:
        fh.write(message)


# File B.py
from A import write_to_file

def part_of_a_big_feature():
    # Do some things
    write_to_file("bla")
    # Do some things


# File feature.py
from B import part_of_a_big_feature

def feature():
    # First part is for a specific feature

    # Second: I called the part_of_a_big_feature
    part_of_a_big_feature()

    # Then another feature

    # Then return
    return 1

# file feature.py
import pytest

from C import feature

class TestException(Exception):
    pass

class TestFeature:
    @staticmethod
    def setup_method():
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def teardown_method():
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def test_feature(mocker):
        # Mocking
        mocker.patch("path.to.A.Bwrite_to_file", return_value=None) # does not work here.
        
        # Tests
        assert feature() == 1

# run it with 'pytest -vv test_my_function.py'
```

I am looking for the right way to make *chain mocking works*

For more details:

- Imagine a function called "test()" defined in **A.py**.
- This function "test()" is imported and used in the file **B.py**, in a function called "function_that_use_test()".
- Then, the function "function_that_use_test()" is imported and used in the file **C.py**, in a function called "function_that_use_function_that_use_test()"

It **could be done N times**. How to mock this with pytest-mock?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is to "mock where it's used, not where it's defined", see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch.

Now, if you want to mock `write_to_file` or `test`, which is used in module `B.py`, you just do:

```
def test_with_mock(mocker):
    mocker.patch('B.write_to_file')  # or mocker.patch('B.test')
```

You don't need to care about the other modules.

Comment: Well, for B case, there is not problem to test. But what about testing C function and mocking write_to_file

Comment: What do you mean? You call the function from 'C' and mock `write_to_file` where it is used.

Comment: You can't because **B import write_to_file** when **C import a function that calls write_to_file**. And you can't mock C.write_to_file neither C.part_of_a_big_feature.write_to_file

Comment: Well, ùy bad, you are right. I was trying to mock something else. Your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like this, if i understand you correctly:

```
#File A.py
def write_to_file(message, file="test.txt"):
    with open(file, "w") as fh:
        fh.write(message)

#File B.py
from A import write_to_file

def part_of_a_big_feature():
    # Do some things
    write_to_file("bla")

    # Do some things



# File feature.py
from B import part_of_a_big_feature


def feature():
    # First part is for a specific feature

    # Second: I called the part_of_a_big_feature
    return part_of_a_big_feature()


def feature_with_exception():
    part_of_a_big_feature()



   if True:
    raise Exception("An anonym exception is thrown")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   feature()
   feature_with_exception()




#test.py

from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from C import feature, feature_with_exception


class TestChainFunction(TestCase):

    def test_with_feature(self):
        with patch("C.part_of_a_big_feature", return_value = None) as part_of_a_big_feature:
            feature()
            self.assertIsNone(feature())

    def test_feature_with_exception(self):
        with patch( "C.part_of_a_big_feature", return_value=None) as part_of_a_big_feature:
            with self.assertRaises(Exception) as error_context:
                feature_with_exception()
            self.assertEqual(
                error_context.exception.args[0],
                'An anonym exception is thrown'
            )
```

Comment: What about write_to_file function? I don't want this function to write anything furing test. So how to mock it ?

Comment: that is the purpose of mocking, if you have chain functions if you mock the last   n-1"th function in the chain, then the others would not be called if you are testing, but in the file, if you call the function directly, you need to use the magic stuff if __name__ == "__main__":  then the name of the function, otherwise it will call the chain functions because of module imports.

Comment: So, your answer is that there is **no way** to mock my function write_to_file in the cases that I try **to mock part_of_a_big_feature** or more "complex" functions